# UI5 navContiner bindAggregation not loading the pages

Tags: sapui5

i need to build the page by binding aggregation as below

view

```
<NavContainer
        id="navCon"
        class="navContainerControl sapUiSmallMarginBottom" height="50%">
</NavContainer>
```

controller

```
onInit : function()
    {
        var navCon = this.getView().byId("navCon");
        navCon.bindAggregation('pages',{
            path:'/pages',
            factory : jQuery.proxy(this.createPages,this)
        });
}

createPages : function(sid,context)
    {
        var eachpageData = context.getObject();
        var grid = new sap.ui.layout.Grid({
            defaultSpan:"L4 M6 S6"
         });
        var page = new sap.m.Page({
            id : eachpageData.name,
            title : eachpageData.name,
            content : grid
        });
        grid.bindAggregation('content',{path:'data',factory :this.createPageContent});
        return page;
    },
```

But when i see from the debugger it has only one page

[image]

But when i call navto

```
handleNav : function(evt)
    {
        var navCon = this.getView().byId("navCon");
        var target = evt.getSource().getText();
        if (target) {
            //var animation = this.getView().byId("animationSelect").getSelectedKey();
            navCon.to(this.getView().byId(target));
        } else {
            navCon.back();
        }
    }
```

and if i see the navCon.getPages() will give 2 pages.
What mistake i have done here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass the DOM element to the **NavContainers.to(DOM)** method. This is where its gone wrong.

But NavContainers.to() method can accept id(String) as parameter.

Change your handleNav method as follows it will work.

```
handleNav : function(evt)
{
    var navCon = this.getView().byId("navCon");
    var target = evt.getSource().getText();
    if (target) {
        navCon.to(target);
    } else {
        navCon.back();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`NavContainers` can display only one page. You can add more pages to the pages aggregation, but they will be visible only if a navigation event is fired with the proper parameters. After that, the layout of the new page is loaded and added to the DOM.

In case of `SplitApp`, application can display two pages (master and detail) if you see it on tablet or desktop; however it's implemented by the use of two `NavContainers`.

That's why the control inspector returns with one page before the navigation, second page is not part of the DOM until you navigates to it.

If you place a breakpoint into your code instead of using the control inspector, you can call the `navCon.getPages()` which should return with the number of pages in the aggregation.

Comment: Can you tell me how can we place the 2nd page to NavContiner.. i am doing this navCon.to(this.getView().byId(target)); but the page not exist so the byId is not working.